# TRACERT Issues, Consistently timing out on specific steps

Tags: isp, traceroute

I've been with the same internet provider (ZoomInternet) for a few years now.  It has been a relatively good experience, and the service is typically fine just fine.

However, the last 2 or 3 days I've had some noticeable latency issues with some of the games I play.  For example, WGT is a golf game, the time it takes to load new images after each shot has greatly increased.  I constantly lag in Agario, sometimes losing the connection completely.  None of this was happening 3 days ago.

So, I do the obligatory computer/modem/router reset.  Release/Renew my IP the whole 9 yards.  I always assume it's me.  However, I haven't installed any new software in a week and I can't find anything that points to me as the problem.  Since this happens on every site I trace, I tend to lean in the "it's not me this time" direction.

When I run a tracert to the WGT gameserver (or Agar.io or even to yahoo.com) I get timeouts in the exact same spot.  Steps 3 and 4.

Here's a screenshot of a few traces I've done: [TraceRt Screenshot](http://vvcap.com/2SCTJUUarzl)

This has been consistently timing out for the last couple of days on steps 3 and 4.  The 209 IP in step 5 is a datacenter in Indianapolis.  Somewhere between Zoom and that Indy IP something is going wrong.

So the support guy asked me to trace armstrongonewire.com (specifically in their backbone).  I got about 10 timeouts in 12 steps before he told me to kill it.  I hit step 2 just like all the other traces fine, then it went to crud from there.

The guy then proceeds to tell me that 'some' servers on the backbone are not setup to return a response to a trace. I've never heard of that before, so this has me baffled.  If the server doesn't respond, how does my computer know the data is getting there? Without a response, wouldn't it just keep sending until a retry timeout?

I've run traces for years, including traces to WGT before, and all steps typically resolved without an issue.  Now I can't seem to get an entire trip to any server fully resolved at every step.  I call BS on this "not configured to respond" explanation.  Doesn't seem legit. What do you guys think?

I'm downloading WinMTR to get a second opinion, but I'm certain something is up with the ISP (or their provider) and they aren't being upfront about, or are oblivious to, the issue.

Here's my MTR results: http://vvcap.com/Ak0yyHjoT09

Has anyone ever heard of 'backbone' servers (or any large-scale network) being specifically configured to NOT send a respond to a trace or ping?

Thanks.

Comment: the "support guy" is telling the truth.  if it truly timed out, you would never reach the destination. it is not uncommon to see time outs at all

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  I know it's getting there.  I can still play the games.  What I'm trying to ascertain is whether there is any truth to the "some servers not configured to respond to a trace".  I think that's a BS explanation and it's not consistent with what I've seen before.  This is obviously not on me based on the traces I've posted.  I'm hitting their backbone fine, but it's getting lost in their backbone somewhere, and they won't acknowledge it.  They want me to call the "game company".  I'm not going to call every website in the world.

Comment: These hops are not timing out, they are not responding, which is normal sometimes... basically they are setup not to return a ping to you. The issue here seems to be a long delay where your carrier hands off their traffic to Zayo... completely out of your hands. Unless your carriers network operations are complete baffoons, they know there is a problem and are just buying time until it gets corrected.

Comment: @acejavelin Ok, this is kinda what I thought from the get-go.  But I was not aware you could actually setup a server to not return a response, so when he said that I felt like I was getting BS'ed.  That answers my question. Just wait it out I guess eh? It's alarming that they seemed to not see anything wrong. Obviously something is.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried tracerouting into that armstrongonewire host, as soon as the tracert ingresses into Zoom's network, no response anywhere. Plus I see tons of packet loss just before ingressing into that network. http://imgur.com/L9CQ03G So there is clearly something wrong, and it maybe outside of your ISP's network, just barely.

Comment: I think they just don't want to throw their own providers under the bus. Thanks for your help and running your own trace.  That's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert at this, so… please point out any nonsense I wrote.

But, yes, that's quite possible, because the packets these diagnostic tools sends & expects *aren't* exactly the same thing as your regular data packets. They don't try to make the same TCP-port-80 connection as your web browser would.

---

The `ping` command is simple – it sends ICMP "Echo" packets (dedicated for this purpose), and expects ICMP "Echo Reply" responses from the target. Since ICMP itself is also used for reporting connection errors, most operating systems already have built-in support for answering Echo requests, however...

- There are some other ICMP packets that aren't quite as useful, for example "Redirect" or even the old "Source Quench" (easy to abuse). Even the same Ping/Echo has a history of being used as the [Ping of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_of_death) against various buggy network stacks.

  As a result, many sysadmins to this day configure a blanket block of *all* incoming ICMP packets, in the belief that this would make their network more secure.

  Sometimes they block even outgoing ICMP packets, which among other things breaks Traceroute as well as other things like MTU discovery. (I mean, it's obviously *their* network and their business, but… argh.)
- While Windows isn't used for routers (much), it is still probably the most common example of this – ever since Windows XP SP3, the built-in firewall would, by default, drop all incoming Echo requests.

(Almost any firewall lets you filter TCP & UDP packets selectively, based on things like source address and/or destination port. So there's no surprise that firewalls can pass TCP but block ICMP, for example.)

---

As for Traceroute, it has no dedicated message or protocol, in fact it *relies on error replies*. The exact implementation varies – on Windows the `tracert` command sends ICMP Echo packets, while most variations of the Linux `traceroute` tool send garbage over UDP instead (although can do ICMP as well). But the common part is that they send the packets with small, increasing "time to live" aka "hop count" limits, expecting each router in the path to reply back with an ICMP "Time-to-live Exceeded" error. Most operating systems do that by default.

But, again, some systems have firewalls set up to silently drop ICMP Echo packets, and as a result they don't send any error message back. (In this case, it seems the filtering only applies to packets that the router itself would handle, but not to packets it merely forwards along.)

Some other systems have firewalls set up to block specifically just outgoing ICMP errors. I've honestly no idea why, but I've seen that happen.

And some routers *do* have the ICMP error generation itself turned off, perhaps to reduce load or to avoid packets being handled by the slow main CPU when they would otherwise be forwarded by fast dedicated hardware.

---

So in the end, it's not that "some routers aren't set up to answer", but more that they "are *set up not to answer*" the traceroute messages.

(I can't really answer why sometimes `mtr` works but no invocation of `traceroute` does. At first look, it does use the same approach as traceroute, but I haven't investigated it in depth.)

Comment: This is great information.  Thanks for taking the time to explain it.